# Existence of a function $f$ with $\mathbb E[X^2f(X)]$ being finite for some $X$ with finite second moment

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E}\newcommand{\PM}{\mathbb P}$This question is inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3027667/349501) which is unfortunately closed. Anyways, I found it interesting, so I tried to solve it.

The problem was as follows:

> **Problem.** Let $X$ be a random variable which has a finite second moment, i.e. $\E[X^2]<\infty$. Show that there exists a non-negative function $f:\mathbb R\to[0,\infty)$ such that the following holds:
>
> 1. $f$ is non-decreasing on $(0,\infty)$
> 2. $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$
> 3. $\E[X^2f(X)]<\infty$

**Attempt.**

Firstly, I thought that $f(x)=\log(1+|x|)$ should do the work, but after some thoughts I have discovered that it is not guaranteed to work.  Secondly, I have considered an Ansatz method which basically ended up with
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} \mathbf{1}_{\{a_k \leq x\}} 
\end{align*}
which has all the properties if $a_k$ is strictly increasing to $\infty$. Now we have
\begin{align*}
\E\left[ X^2 f(X)\right]&=\E\left[X^2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}\mathbf{1}_{\{a_k\leq  X \}}\right]\\
&\stackrel{\text{Fatou}}{\leq} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1 k \E[X^2\mathbf{1}_{\{a_k\leq X \}}]
\end{align*}
I really would like to have
\begin{align*}\tag{$*$}
\E[X^2\mathbf{1}_{\{a_k\leq X \}}]\leq \frac 1 {k^\alpha}
\end{align*}
for some $\alpha>0$. We know that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{y\to\infty} \E[X^2 \mathbf{1}_{\{y\leq X\}}]\stackrel{\text{DCT}}{=}0
 \end{align*}
which means that we can find a sequence $a_k$ stricly increasing to infinity satisfying $(*)$. We have constructed $f$ with all the properties.

> **Question.** Are there other methods for constructing such function $f$? Can it be done easier?

To be honest, it costed me a couple of trials to actually come up with an example.

Comment: related? http://canizo.org/tex/vallee-poussin.pdf

Comment: @CalvinKhor yes, thanks!!

Comment: I don't have time to make an answer from that, but glad to help